# Ruby's digits method performance

Tags: ruby, performance

I'm solving some Project Euler problems using Ruby, and specifically here I'm talking about problem 25 (What is the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?).

At first, I was using Ruby `2.2.3` and I coded the problem as such:

```
number = 3
a = 1
b = 2

while b.to_s.length < 1000
  a, b = b, a + b
  number += 1
end
puts number
```

But then I found out that version `2.4.2` has a method called `digits` which is exactly what I needed. I transformed to code to:

```
while b.digits.length < 1000
```

And when I compared the two methods, `digits` was much slower.

**Time**

`./025/problem025.rb  0.13s user 0.02s system 80% cpu 0.190 total`

`./025/problem025.rb  2.19s user 0.03s system 97% cpu 2.275 total`

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: `digits` builds and populates an array. This isn't cheap.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Then why is `b.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reverse` about five times faster than `b.digits` for me? That also creates the same array, and in a much more laborious way.

Comment: @StefanPochmann [can't reproduce](https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/a48ac7e8406f6ad28b1372e43a73c0c0)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: hmm, this number is too small. With longer numbers digits indeed becomes significantly slower. :shrug: Still it builds an array (not cheap). And some other expensive things too :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: but `.to_s.length` [runs circles around both variants](https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/a48ac7e8406f6ad28b1372e43a73c0c0) anyway

Comment: Frank: while unrelated to this question, just want to let you know that there's a constant time (yes, O(1)) solution here. Involving a bit of math. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Seriously? I would certainly like to know!

Comment: Related to the question... I still don't get it!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev And [`BigDecimal` is laughing](https://gist.github.com/pochmann/0cee969252f3405a082797f8746be8f4) at `to_s`.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that module. Really performant.

Comment: Well, presumably `BigDecimal` stores its data in decimal instead of binary and simply *knows* the exponent. Base conversion isn't cheap. That's also what I suspect is the culprit making `digits` slow, maybe it uses a different and slower algorithm for base conversion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby's `digits`

- ... is [implemented in `rb_int_digits`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L5453).
- Which for non-tiny numbers (i.e., most of your numbers) [uses `rb_int_digits_bigbase`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L4848).
- Which extracts digit after digit [naively with division/modulo by base](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L4810-L4814).
- So it should take **quadratic time** (at least with a small base such as 10).

Ruby's `to_s`

- ... is [implemented in `int_to_s`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L5392).
- Which [uses `rb_int2str`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L3465).
- Which for non-tiny numbers [uses `rb_big2str`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L3475).
- Which [uses `rb_big2str1`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/bignum.c#L5064).
- Which [might use `big2str_gmp` if available](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/bignum.c#L5054) (which [sounds/looks like](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/bignum.c#L4982-L5012) it uses the fast [**GMP** library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library)) or ...
- ... [uses `big2str_generic`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/bignum.c#L5058).
- Which [uses `big2str_karatsuba`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/bignum.c#L4961) (sweet, I recognize that name!).
- Which [looks like](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/bignum.c#L4738) it has something to do with ...
- ... [**Karatsuba**'s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), which is a fast multiplication algorithm. If you multiply two n-digit numbers the naive way you learned in school, you take n<sup>2</sup> single-digit products. Karatsuba on the other hand only needs about **n<sup>1.585</sup>**, which is quite a lot better. And I didn't read into this further, but I suspect what Ruby does here is also this efficient. [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540587/1672429) with a base conversion algorithm uses Karatsuba multiplication and says *"this [base conversion] algorithm is utterly dominated by the cost of the multiplication"*.

Comparing quadratic to n<sup>1.585</sup> over the number lengths from 1 digit to 1000 digits gives factor 15:

```
(1..1000).sum { |i| i**2 } / (1..1000).sum { |i| i**1.585 }
=> 15.150583254950678
```

Which is roughly the factor you observed as well. Of course that's a rather naive comparison, but, well, why not.

GMP by the way apparently uses/used a ["near O(n * log(n)) FFT-based multiplication algorithm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521676/convert-very-huge-number-to-base-10-string/9540587#comment12089322_9540587).

Thanks to @Drenmi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956172/1672429) for motivating me to dig into the source after all. I hope I did this right, no guarantees, I'm a Ruby beginner. But that's why I left all the links there for you to check for yourself :-P

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It was a bit tedious, but already the joy of seeing "big2str_karatsuba" was worth it :-) (I learned and implemented Karatsuba's algorithm almost 20 years ago but rarely ever came across it afterwards).

Comment: Although I'm not a C expert, it was nice trying to read some docs and diving deeper on these algorithms such as Karatsuba and FFT. Thank you @StefanPochmann for this excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

`Integer#digits` doesn't just "split" the number. From the documentation:

> Returns the array including the digits extracted by place-value
>   notation with radix base of int.

This extraction is done even if a `base` argument is omitted. The relevant source:

```
# ruby/numeric.c:4809

while (!FIXNUM_P(num) || FIX2LONG(num) > 0) {
    VALUE qr = rb_int_divmod(num, base);
    rb_ary_push(digits, RARRAY_AREF(qr, 1));
    num = RARRAY_AREF(qr, 0);
}
```

As you can see, this process includes repeated modulo arithmetics, which likely accounts for the additional runtime.

Comment: That documentation sentence describes the result, not the process. Also, I think you're showing the wrong code. That's in `rb_fix_digits`, which as far as I can tell is for Fixnum numbers and thus pretty irrelevant here since Frank's program does almost nothing with Fixnums.

Comment: Though I think [this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/daaebaec79f60796b9c864907ad03d1e02b93fb2/numeric.c#L4810-L4814) is the actually relevant code and it does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: You're right @StefanPochmann. Changed the reference to the right line in `numeric.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Many ruby methods create objects (strins, arrays, etc.)
In ruby, object creation in ruby is "expensive".

For instance `to_s` creates a string and `digits` creates an array every time the while condition is evaluated.

If you want to optimize your example, you can do the following:

```
# create the smallest possible 1000 digits number
max = 10**999

number = 3
a = 1
b = 2

# do not create objects in while condition
while b < max
  a, b = b, a + b
  number += 1
end
puts number
```

Comment: `max = 10**999`

Comment: Thomas: Numbers are objects, too, so "do not create objects" isn't quite right. And I think the string/array creation argument is a red herring, partly because that's a small part of the work and partly because the numbers do build (internal) arrays as well. But good idea to solve it this way. It's (unsurprisingly) even faster than my previous winner using `BigDecimal`, about twice as fast: https://gist.github.com/pochmann/0cee969252f3405a082797f8746be8f4

Answer (score 0):

I have not answered your question, but wish to suggest an improved algorithm for the problem you have addressed. For a given number of decimal digits, `n`, I have implemented the following algorithm.

- estimate the number `f` of Fibonacci numbers ("FNs") that have `n` or fewer decimal digits.
- compute the f<sup>th</sup> and (f-1)<sup>st</sup> FNs, and the number of digits `m` in the f<sup>th</sup> FN.
- if `m >= n` back down from  down from the (f-1)<sup>st</sup> FN until the (f-1)<sup>st</sup> FN has fewer than `n` decimal digits, at which time the f<sup>th</sup> FN is the smallest FN to have `n` decimal digits.
- if `m < n` increase the f<sup>th</sup> FN until the it has `n` decimal digits, at which time it is the smallest FN to have `n` decimal digits.

The key is to compute a close estimate `f` in the first step.

**Code**

```
AVG_FNs_PER_DIGIT = 4.784971966781667

def first_fibonacci_with_n_digits(n)
  return [1, 1] if n == 1
  idx = (n * AVG_FNs_PER_DIGIT).round
  fn, prev_fn = fib(idx)
  fn.to_s.size >= n ? fib_down(n, fn, prev_fn, idx) : fib_up(n, fn, prev_fn, idx)
end

def fib(idx)
  a = 1
  b = 2
  (idx - 2).times {a, b = b, a + b }
  [b, a] 
end

def fib_up(n, b, a, idx)
  loop do
    a, b = b, a + b
    idx += 1
    break [idx, b] if b.to_s.size == n
  end
end

def fib_down(n, b, a, idx)
  loop do
    a, b = b - a, a
    break [idx, b] if a.to_s.size == n - 1
    idx -= 1
  end
end
```

**Benchmarks**

In computing each Fibonacci number two operations are typically performed:

- compute the number of digits in the last-computed Fibonacci number and if that  number is equal to the target number of digits, terminate (for reasons made clear in the *Explanation* section below, it cannot be larger than the target number); else
- compute the next number in the Fibonacci sequence.

By contrast, the method I have proposed performs the first step a relatively small number of times.

How important is the first step relative to the second and how does the use of  `n.digits.size` compare with that of `n.to_s.size` in the first step? Let's run some benchmarks to find out.

```
def use_to_s(ndigits)
  case ndigits
  when 1
    [1, 1]
  else
    a = 1
    b = 2
    idx = 3
    loop do
      break [idx, b] if b.to_s.length == ndigits
      a, b = b, a + b
      idx += 1
    end
  end
end

def use_digits(ndigits)
  case ndigits
  when 1
    [1, 1]
  else
    a = 1
    b = 2
    idx = 3
    loop do
      break [idx, b] if b.digits.size == ndigits
      a, b = b, a + b
      idx += 1
    end
  end
end
```

```
require 'fruity'

def test(ndigits)
  nfibs, last_fib = use_to_s(ndigits)
  puts "\nndigits = #{ndigits}, nfibs=#{nfibs}, last_fib=#{last_fib}"
  compare do
    try_use_to_s   { use_to_s(ndigits) }
    try_use_digits { use_digits(ndigits) }
    try_estimate   { first_fibonacci_with_n_digits(ndigits) }
  end
end
```

```
test 20
ndigits = 20, nfibs=93, last_fib=12200160415121876738
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
try_estimate is faster than try_use_to_s by 2x ± 0.1
try_use_to_s is faster than try_use_digits by 80.0% ± 10.0%
```

```
test 100
ndigits = 100, nfibs=476, last_fib=13447...37757 (90 digits omitted)
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 4 seconds.
try_estimate is faster than try_use_to_s by 5x ± 0.1
try_use_to_s is faster than try_use_digits by 10x ± 1.0
```

```
test 500
ndigits = 500, nfibs=2390, last_fib=13519...63145 (490 digits omitted)
Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 27 seconds.
try_estimate is faster than try_use_to_s by 9x ± 0.1
try_use_to_s is faster than try_use_digits by 60x ± 1.0
```

```
test 1000
ndigits = 1000, nfibs=4782, last_fib=10700...27816 (990 digits omitted)
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 minute.
try_estimate is faster than try_use_to_s by 12x ± 10.0
try_use_to_s is faster than try_use_digits by 120x ± 100.0
```

There are two main take-aways from these results:

- "try_estimate" is the fastest because it performs the first step relatively few times; and
- the use of `to_s` is much faster than that of `digits`.

Further to the first of these observations note that the initial estimates of  the index of the first FN having a given number of digits, compared to the actual index, are as follows:

- for   20 digits:   96 est. vs   93 actual
- for  100 digits:  479 est. vs  476 actual
- for  500 digits: 2392 est. vs 2390 actual
- for 1000 digits: 4785 est. vs 4782 actual

The deviation was at most 3, meaning numbers of digits had to be calculated for at most 3 FNs to obtain the desired result.

**Explanation**

The only explanation of the methods given in the section *Code* above is the derivation of the constant `AVG_FNs_PER_DIGIT`, which is used to calculate an estimate of the index of the first FN having the specified number of digits.

The derivation of this constant derives from the question and selected answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834040/relationship-between-decimal-length-and-fibonacci-number). (The [Wiki for Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) provides a good overview of the mathematical properties of FNs.)

It is known that the first 7 FNs (including zero) have one digit; thereafter the FNs gain an additional digit every 4 or 5 FNs (i.e., sometimes 4, else 5). Therefore, as a very crude calculation, we see that to calculate the first FN with `n` digits, `n >= 2`, it will not be less than the `4*n`th FN. For `n = 1000`, that would be 4,000. (In fact, the 4,782nd is the smallest to have 1,000 digits.) In other words, we don't need to calculate the number of digits in the first 4,000 FNs. We can improve on this estimate, however.

As `n` approaches infinity, the ratio of ranges `10**n...10**(n+1)` (`n`-digit intervals) that contain 5 FNs to those that contain 4 FNs can be computed as follows.

```
LOG_10 = Math.log(10)
  #=> 2.302585092994046
GR = (1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2
  #=> 1.618033988749895
LOG_GR = Math.log(GR)
  #=> 0.48121182505960347

RATIO_5to4 = (LOG_10 - 4*LOG_GR)/(5*LOG_GR - LOG_10)
  #=> 3.6505564183095474
```

where `GR` is the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Over a large number of n-digit intervals let n<sub>4</sub> be the number of those intervals containing 4 FNs and n<sub>5</sub> be the number containing 5 FNs. The average number of FNs per interval is therefore (n<sub>4</sub>*4 + n<sub>5</sub>*5)/(n<sub>4</sub> + n<sub>5</sub>). Since n<sub>5</sub>/n<sub>4</sub> converges to `RATIO_5to4`, n<sub>5</sub> approaches `RATIO_5to4` * n<sub>4</sub> in the limit (discarding roundoff error). If we substitute out n<sub>5</sub>, and let

```
b = 1/(1 + RATIO_5to4)
  #=> 0.21502803321833364
```

we find the average number of FNs per n-digit interval converges to

```
avg = b * 4 + (1-b) *5
  #=> 4.784971966781667
```

If `fn` is the first FN to have `n` decimal digits, the number of FNs in the sequence up to an including `fn` can therefore be approximated to be

```
n * avg
```

If, for example, the estimate of the index of the first FN to have 1000 decimal digits would be `1000 * 4.784971966781667).round #=> 4785`.